# preg_replace Parse error: syntax error in function

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to integrate GeSHi syntax highlighter into my blog.

I am getting a syntax error in my code. I am not very good with PHP code hence seeking help in correcting the syntax.

**My code is :**

```
private function _renderCode($string)
{
    return preg_replace('/<listing (.*?)>(.*?)</listing>/es',
                '$this->highlightString('\2', '\1')', 
                $string);
}
```

**The Error Message is :**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'$this->highlightString(\'\\2\', \'\\1\')',`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the syntax highlighting:

```
'$this->highlightString('\2', '\1')'
```

You need to escape the single quotes in a single-quoted string.

```
'$this->highlightString(\'\2\', \'\1\')'
```

(And the preferred form is `'$this->highlightString(\'$2\', \'$1\')'`, by the way.)